# Have something happen

Tags: grammar

As in "I had that happen before." Why is this correct? Does this mean that something has happened to someone or that you made/let something happen?

Comment: Do you think it is correct?

Comment: In *most* contexts, *I had that happen before* simply means *I underwent that situation/experience before*, but in certain contexts it could carry the implication *I **caused** that to happen before*. I don't think there are any contexts where it could imply *I **let/allowed** that to happen before*.

Answer (score 2):

> I had **that** happen before

In this sentence, **that** is referring to the thing or event that *happened*. It's not specified what caused the event, or who or what it happened to. It just happened.

The person is saying, in effect, *I have had previous experience of this event*, and the assumption is that the person he or she is speaking to understands the subject under discussion.