# Why is 'bare-verb go' in this sentence?

Tags: verbs, spoken-english, bare-infinitives

I posted the question about the sentence below what 'had' means in this sentence.

> One individual **had** a bullet as a child **go** right through the left temporal lobe.

Thanks to stangdon, I got it that here 'had' means 'experienced'. [see the details](https://youtu.be/vue8jsLqPbo?t=114)

But I have another question... about 'go'

1. Why is the speaker saying bare verb 'go'?
2. If the sentence is rewritten, how it could be?

[Here](https://youtu.be/vue8jsLqPbo?t=114) is the video including the sentence above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Have" and "make" can function as causative verbs in the pattern 
"[have (something) + verb](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/let.html)".  Other verbs don't have this pattern, and either take a to-infinitive (eg. "get (something) to do (something)", or a gerund, eg "experienced (something) doing (something)".

The sense here is not really causative, (it is the [Have something happen](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88532/have-something-happen/88542) meaning). But it is this pattern that is appearing.

So "One individual experienced, as a child, a bullet going right through their left temporal lobe."

Answer (score 1):

"Had" does basically mean "experienced" here, except that associated verb form is different. With this sense of "had," the associated verb should be in the infinitive, whereas "experienced" takes an -ing form. For instance, the corresponding sentence to your example would be

> One individual, as a child, experienced a bullet going right through the left temporal lobe.

(I moved the "as a child" because it is poorly placed and sounds almost as if the bullet was a child.)

A similar sentence using "had" would be

> One time I had a tree fall on my house.

which is equivalent to

> One time I experienced a tree falling on my house.